# Issue with Create method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a website developed in Laravel hosted in 2 different servers, in both the site is working, but there is a section that only works in only one of the server.

Clicking on a button the whole website freezes. I kept track of every line of code that gets executed and the line to "blame" is:

```
$var= UserTask::create(array('task_id' => $taskProgress->id));
```

How can this instruction have a different behavior on two different servers?

Comment: What server are you using? Can you show us the model code?

Comment: Also: what do you mean with freezes? White screen? Or do you get an error (maybe in your error logs?)

Comment: What does laravel.log say about this? Have you tried to switch to development mode? This should output the error.

Answer (score 0):

Enable debugging in your app/config/app.php file

'debug' => True;

Fire the Task again and see if you get any error. You may also check the Laravel log in /app/storage/logs

Comment: Debug mode was on, no messages..

Plus, I detected that crashes happens in that line of code by putting Log::info('check X') on every line of code.

Not very scientific, I know, but now I know that app is crashing at that line